# How to debug Xamarin.Android App with PRIVILEGED access?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I face with issue in `Xamarin.Android` application that I cannot call `bleDevice.SetPairingConfirmation(true)` even with set `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` manifest, because I got the exception that do not have `PRIVILEGED` permission

I tried to run application in debug mode in both `Rider` and `Visual Studio`

I have found the similar issue https://forum.khadas.com/t/bluetooth-pairing/2731/2 and seems like it is related to how application is installed in debug mode

Is there a proper solution for debugging application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out, it happens because application is not installed with root access rights ...

It is allowed only to installed system applications